# How would an oligarchy dedicated to economic growth rule?

Tags: economy, politics, history

The nation in question is a One Party State, and has been for nearly five centuries. The party leaders are oligarchs in every sense of the term, deriving massive incomes from their control over the nation's resources.

...but because the nation already had established industry and a rich history of trade, they didn't establish an extractive state. Instead, the leadership maintains a managerial role where they basically own most of the land in the country and compete to increase economic growth to supplement their incomes. They are mostly factory owners, rich farmers, millers, financiers, and merchants. A dictatorship of the Bourgeoisie in every sense of the term.

Now what I want to get some help on is the specific policies they will have instituted, along with their general political ideologies and doctrines. My base assumptions are that they will rule like the early modern English Parliamentarians, with enclosures to grow wool and colonial plantations to grow cash crops with. I expect laissez-faire economics where anything goes as long as it doesn't cause riots or revolutionary sentiment. I also expect patronage of education and the sciences to better help in keeping their scientific edge, and state patronage plus military interventions to deal with affairs of international trade and commerce.

Am I right? What else can I add? Any institutions I should consider developing in particular?

Comment: In most of human history, One Party Rule has tended to stop economic growth as growth tends to disrupt the social order leading to changing of those in power. The places that have gone for economic growth have external enemies that need to be defeated and the growth is about growing the military to defeat the enemy. The Romans always needed wars on the edges of the empire.

Comment: ??? You do know that Japan (ruled continuously by the Liberal Democratic Party since 1955, except 3 years in 2009 to 2012), Singapore, South Korea, and Taiwan do exist in the real world, yes? How hard is it to find out how these four rich countries became rich after the second world war, how did the ruling parties rule, what economic, political and social policies they followed?

Comment: @DavidR: [*Pax Romana*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pax_Romana) is a real thing. From the late 1st century BCE to the late 2nd century CE the Roman empire fought exactly two significant wars of conquest, emperor Claudius in Britain 78 to 84 CE, and emperor Trajan in Dacia 101 to 106 CE. (And only Trajan's conquest of Dacia did bring in signficant amounts of gold and silver.) Other than those two campaigns, the only non-negligible military engagements were in the neverending, thousand-years long competition with the Persian Empire, which never produced any important income.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The only time you should be aware of the Government is when you have to interact with it**

The Oligarchs are otherwise invisible to the Common Man - the individual is able to live their life, as they see fit, which means they are not inclined to any form of Revolution.

The Foundation of this is a strong, transparent and *fair* legal system. So long as people don't believe that Money and or Status gives someone an advantage when it comes to the Law, they will be mostly happy

Furthermore, There would be a limited form of Social Welfare, but there would be checks/balances - People can be quite generous to others who have suffered unforseen circumstances, but they are less generous to those who continue to make the same mistakes.

Finally - and this is perhaps most important:

**They would need to foster a single point of National Unity**

Whether that's religion, National Pride, Adversary to a common Enemy, Sport - whatever.

When people have something that Unites them, they are less likely to revolt and more likely to work harder for the common good - but you can't force this - it must be Voluntary.

Answer (score 5):

To meet your requirements, the oligarchy would have to do three things. First, they have to **maintain power for centuries.** If they fail to do that, they cannot pursue policies for centuries. Second, they need to do the thing you specified, to **promote economic growth.** And third, given the timescale you want, they have to **sustain the environment.** Unless failing in the third goal is part of your storyline.

One issue they face is that economic growth will require technological progress, and technological progress will require an educated workforce.

- They will have to weather the transition from the primary sector of economy (agriculture is leading, and also mining) to the secondary sector (manufacturing is leading) and the tertiary sector (services). They will have to predict and lead the wave, not cling to outmoded income sources. Invest the wealth from farms in factories, invest the wealth from factories in franchises. They need to **fund think tanks** which tell them what they do not want to hear when they have grown up believing that only *real* estate is real ...
  One of the things I could see is a really **strong patent and intellectual property law**, with oligarchs holding key patents.
- As they progress, they will need an increasingly **educated workforce.** An illiterate serf may be able to drive an oxcart, but a tractor driver needs to be able to read and understand manuals, and the programmer of a GPS-controlled agricultural drone needs to be able to think creatively.
  You will see [Taylorist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_management) approaches and payment by [piece rates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piece_work), but increasingly that gets difficult as "success" of a worker is harder to measure. They can tell how many rivets a riveter has punched that day, or how many burgers a fast food cook has flipped, but can they tell how the planned irrigation canal will hold out under once-in-a-century flooding conditions, if they do not do the math themselves? They will need a way to co-opt [knowledge workers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_worker) without diluting their own power.

The way to that is to have **many different social classes** below the top level of the oligarchy, and *some* potential of social mobility.

- Consider *transparency* of class distinctions at the lower classes, coupled with *intransparency* at the top.
  A skilled factory worker should know *exactly* what sets him or her apart from an unskilled worker, what privileges this skill gets over the lower classes, and how to perform to earn promotion to foreman or even supervisor. Demotion is a constant threat, promotion is a constant lure. Each class should believe that distribution of wealth between themselves and those below them is necessarily a zero-sum game, with no idea of just how much gets skimmed by those above.
  *In the real world, there is this joke: The capitalist, the worker, and the refugee sit around a table with a dozen cookies. The capitalist takes eleven of the cookies and tells the worker, 'be careful, the refugee wants part of your cookie.'*
- It will be necessary to offer ways for the most skilled non-oligarchs to enter the oligarchy, or something very close to it. Oligarchs may sneer at these *new money* classes, but in each social class the best and the brightest can earn a step up if they do not rock the boat.
- At the same time, they must ruthlessly suppress *revolutionary* activity. They increase the **fear of chaos and instability** among the non-oligarch classes. Make sure that simple workers live from daily wage to daily wage, with little or no ability to save for rainy days. To enable this, introduce **mandatory pension and health insurance schemes**. Much better if the government holds those funds.
  For the middle and upper classes, set expensive **expectations of respectable behaviour**. They earn more, but they are expected to appear in the office in a not-too-shabby suit, and to be seen at the opera in evening clothes. Those promotion chances I mentioned, they are **not just raw ability**, they also require the candidate to behave as if he or she already was in the higher class, without having the required salaries *yet*. That will leave them in debt to a patron.
- Introduce **mandatory schooling** for all children, covering half the day (say five hours from breakfast to noon). Ostensibly meritocratic, lower class students will have to balance homework with household chores, middle class students get tips and encoragement from their housewife mother, upper class students get supplemental lessons from private tutors. Students get divided into [different academic tracks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracking_(education)) at an early age, when the upbringing overshadows their innate potential.
  A better boarding school for their kids is one of the rewards for highly skilled commoners who support the system.

I described these policies from a power politics viewpoint, but they *may* also be helpful generating economic growth. They bring the means to reward estate managers who come up with a better crop rotation scheme, or mechanics who come up with a better seed drill.

As to the last point, sustainability, perhaps this could be an issue the think tanks mentioned above could support. They were used to manage the transition into and out of industrialism, and now they are saying that fossil fuel has to end ASAP ...

- The oligarchy needs a way to phase out technologies and income sources, without disruptive resistance by the oligarchs in charge of those sectors. They will have to be 'bought off' with a piece in the action in some future technology. Sooner or later, each oligarch will own a **diversified portfolio**.